# Performing regression on unbalanced dataset - algorithm and performance metric

Tags: regression, machine-learning, count-data, model-evaluation

I wish to use regression to predict the number of "useful votes" some product reviews will get. However, most of the data have few or zero votes. This renders the usual MAE or MSE completely useless as the algorithm just learns to predict values close to 0 regardless of the input given.

1. What performance metric can I use to better quantify the performance of my regressor?
2. How do I handle this case of imbalanced dataset besides oversample or undersample examples?

Comment: This is count data.  How did you model it? Maybe start with (zero-inflated) poisson or negbin model?  Maybe that solves the problem, if not, maybe measuring prediction error relatively, not absolutely?

Comment: I would query why you see this as a problem. It is just the way the outcome is and you need to find an appropriate model rather than try to sample it away. @kjetilbhalvorsen has made a useful suggestion which is the way I would have gone too.